# Flash AS Event Properties: Possible to trace them with a for loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flash-cs4

I was wondering if it was possible to use a for (or for each) loop to trace the properties of an event to the output window. I know I can trace the event in one go, like this:

```
function myFunct (evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(evt);
}
```

Unfortunately this gets a little crazy to read in some situations, such as a long URL path, so I would like to reformat it a bit to show each property on its own line, something like this:

```
function URLLoader_IOError (evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    for each(var prop in evt)
    {
        trace(prop)
    }
}
```

Of course, this example isn't showing anything in the output window. Am I missing something in the function or is this just not doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you find the named properties you want to trace and trace those specifically. Properties that would be useful are `errorId`, `text` and `type`. Possibly `eventPhase` as well.

As your code stands, you will be trying to convert objects to string representations. What is `trace` supposed to do with the `currentTarget` property, for example? And do you really care about the `bubbles` property of `IOErrorEvent`? Or 'constructor'?

Alternatively, you can do a lot of testing in your loop to determine what kind of data type you're dealing with, and convert some of its properties to strings for tracing, but at the end of the day you'll still have to use the debugger to examine objects in depth.

Comment: I agree with you on necessity and EOD points. I was just curious if it was possible to make the output a little more accessible for the novice in training situations. If it's not a quickie similar to above, then time would be better spent showing them how to read the raw event trace anyway. Thanks!